# How can I get rid of the first two lines of multiple text files?

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I am trying to get rid of the first two lines of multiple text files. I know the command to do it for just one file using

```
sed -i '1,2d' filename.dat
```

But how can I run this command for multiple files? Can I do this using .sh file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` takes multiple file names as arguments. Just pass them along:

```
sed -i '1,2d' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

If you file names follow a certain pattern, you can take help from shell globbing e.g. for the above:

```
sed -i '1,2d' file{1..3}.txt
```

For all `.dat` files in the current directory:

```
sed -i '1,2d' *.dat
```

Comment: Note for those wishing to *simulate* this without the `-i` (`--in-place`) option, you will need to add the `-s` (`--separate`) flag, otherwise only the first two lines of the first input file will be affected (`-i` with multiple files *implies* `-s` since it wouldn't make sense otherwise).